# Javascript: is it possible to read the raw code of external scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Given a typical script tag:

```
<script src="foo.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

would it be possible to directly read the contents of `myscript.js` as a string or something?
For example:

```
<script id="myscript" src="foo.com/myscript.js"></script>
<script>
    var inners = document.getElementById("myscript").//raw contents of myscript.js
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can read the contents of the inline script tag, because it actually does have content:

```
<script id="myscript">
  var inners = document.getElementById("myscript").textContent;
</script>
```

But for the external JS, the script contents are not actually put into the DOM; you would need to re-fetch it using AJAX (it would normally be cached unless anti-caching measures were taken, so you would not really take much time to re-fetch).

Comment: The question doesn't ask to read the contents of the script *element*, it asks to read the contents of `myscript.js`, so from what you've said actually you *could* read the content by getting a reference to the element by id, using that to get the src property, and then doing an Ajax request to get that resource as a string? (Or just specifying the script url directly for Ajax, if known.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I know what it asks; and I have answered it. Yes, taking `src` from `script` and then making AJAX request is basically the best you can do for external scripts.